# How to show self-defined function on date in the "Appearance -> Labeled" of Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, date-and-time, labeling, plot-themes

I have a plot as below:-

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x*t/40000], {x, -6.6, 6.6}], {t, 30000, 40000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

The `t` is in fact the number of days from Jan. 1, 1900. For example, the input `DateObject[{1900, 1, 1}] + Quantity[35000, "Days"]` would give me `DateObject[{1995, 10, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", -4.]` as output.

How can I change the code such that the label inside the red circle become the date, instead of just the value of `t`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x*t/40000], {x, -6.6, 6.6}],
 {t, 30000, 40000, Labeled[Manipulator[##], 
    DateObject[{1900, 1, 1}] + Quantity[t, "Days"] , Right] &}]
```

or

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x*t/40000], {x, -6.6, 6.6}], 
 Row[{Control@{t, 30000, 40000}, 
   Dynamic[DateObject[{1900, 1, 1}] + Quantity[t, "Days"]]}]]
```

[image]